# How to send notification from one android device to another android device in same wifi network

Tags: android, http, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification from one android device (android tv without bluetooth, telephony) to another android device (phone/tablet). Both are on same wifi network. Through the notification, I want to launch an app or open a page in phone/tablet browser.

I went through GCM messaging and also saw some options where we can have a kind of http server on the phone running but could not understand implementation.

Can someone help with idea and if possible, some piece of code as well.

As I need it for demo, so even any hack solution is fine for me :-)

Thanks for any help or reading.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet as a hacky solution is to do simple Socket connection between two devices. Since they are on same Wifi, it will be simpler and won't have any firewall restrictions.

Avoid GCM, it requires setting up a GCM Server and then complex registration. It also makes your solution dependent upon Internet connectivity & Google ofcourse.

See an example here:
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html

Basically one device such as TV can be a socket listener. The phone/tablet can connect to that socket and then you can initiate a notification on either device based on your requirements and data exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking for some kind of socket related solution only. Will try the link you shared. I want to send notification from TV to phone/tablet. If it works, will accept you answer..